# Can I post data without using submit button

Tags: php, html, submit

I am in a situation using two submit buttons in a same page. Is there any alternative to post data without using submit button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want a submit button, you can do so using links too.

```
<a href="#" onclick="submit_form(); return false;">Submit</a>

<script>
function submit_form()
{
  document.form_name_here.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: you should probably use `document.getElementById("formname").submit();` instead

Answer (score 5):

yes using javascript, you can call form.submit

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For server-side form submission simulation, curl (and php built-in libcurl) can be used to issue POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using javascript. But perhaps you should reconsider your applications flow.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.form_name.submit();
document.form_name_1.submit();
```